# How to store the recorded audio file in SDCard in android emulator?

Tags: android, audio, android-emulator

I am working on audio recording. I can store the file using `file.getAbosolutPath() method`.
It stores the file in path:    /data/data/com.example.audio_demo/files/output.amr

I want store that in `SDCARD.iso` and how retrieve that and play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SDCARD.iso is filename in your filesystem containing /sdcard directory from emulator filesystem, so you can just save file in /sdcard